# Terraform upgrade from 0.11 to 0.12 getting error Invalid value for "lists" parameter in join function

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, iaas

I am upgrading our code from **Terraform 0.11** to **0.12.29**.

my older code that works on TF 0.11

**my.tf**:

```
data "templ_file" "dep" {
    template = "$${input}"

    vars {
        input = "${join(",", var.abc)}"
    }
}
```

Where `abc` is defined as:

```
variable "abc" {
    default = []
    type = list
}
```

Updated **my.tf** to following for TF 0.12.29:

```
...
vars = {
    input = join(",", var.abc)
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Error: Invalid function argument

  on ../modules/x/y/my.tf line 6, in data "templ_file" "dep":
   6:         input = join(",", var.abc)
    |----------------
    | var.abc is list of list of dynamic with 1 element

Invalid value for "lists" parameter: incorrect list element type: string
required.
```

I also saw this post: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/20705 which suggest to use `concat` or `flatten` but I could not make it work.
I am new to terraform so this might be simple question but I am unable to get this working.

Comment: What is the actual value of your variable?

Comment: It looks like you might have a nested list there. If you change your variable definition to have a type of `list(string)` to be stricter (`list` is the equivalent of `list(any)`) you should get a clearer error message. This normally comes about because HCL1 in Terraform 0.11 and below allowed you to wrap lists in square brackets and still come out with a normal list instead of a nested list. This isn't the case in HCL2 and Terraform 0.12+ and you need to be more aware of your types in general.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin @ydaetskcoR, Changing the definition to `list(string)` seem to have resolved the issue as I don't see that error msg now. However, I am not very clear as to why it worked, could you please explain?

Comment: Based on the error message, I think you hit a bug in Terraform 0.12 here where the `join` function wasn't correctly handling the case where the element type of the list was unknown ("dynamic", in this error message). Empty brackets `[]` don't include an example element to decide the element type, so Terraform relies on the type constraint to know what you intended. `list(string)` therefore makes it work even when it's empty. With all of that said, I think this has been addressed in later versions of Terraform so that an empty list of unknown type is accepted as a list of strings.

Comment: Explicitly stating what element type you intend is a good practice anyway, to make it clearer how to use a particular variable, so I'd suggest keeping the `list(string)` even if `list` _does_ work in later Terraform versions.

Comment: @MartinAtkins Thanks for the explanation, that helps.